# PHPStorm head method failed

Tags: phpstorm

Attempted to add a project from a server on a remote host. I can SSH & SFTP without PHPStorm in no prob. The first error I encounter is attempting to select my remote server; when I test the connect, it is successful. When I do not check off 'Don't check HTTP connection to server', I get:

```
Connection to 'Server' failed.
HEAD method failed for "ip address" with HTTP status 401.
```

If I enable `Don't check HTTP connection to server`, I can proceed and I am brought to a list of all directories on my remote server. I select my project as the project root, and attempt to download. Collecting files goes smoothly, and downloading goes by well until a particular file is reached. Error msg:

```
Downloading Project Files failed: failed to transfer file 'wireframes.scssc': channel is not opened.
```

I tried to exclude that directory from download, but it had no effect.

The apache server is configured with basic access authentication. I disabled mod_auth_basic (as confirmed in php.ini), but am still prompted for credentials even after an apache restart. This is second issue preventing me from exploring this potential solution. Any suggestions?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH3GQ.jpg

Comment: IDE tries to verify if there is a working site at that address. If you have put wrong details there (i.e. (S)FTP instead of your HTTP server) then obviously it will be an error. The required authorisation may also be the reson. therefore just check that option off and ignore this part completely.

Comment: I believe I put the correct credentials because when I click 'Test my connection', it says it can connect. I turned off basic access authentication, but it did not change PHPStorm's behaviour.

Comment: Basically, you should just enable that `Don't check HTTP connection to server` to skip such check. I do not use New Project Wizard myself so don't remember the exact name of that option and if it would have been on or off. With your screenshot I see that it must be "on".

Comment: I have enabled that option, but when attempting to download the project files, eventually it reaches 'Downloading Project Files failed: channel is not opened'.

Comment: That's sounds like some sort of timeout for me. The library used by PhpStorm does not really support keep-alive sort of commends and very "sensitive" to operational environment, together with the way it is used by the devs, of course (e.g. if something goes wrong it just stops instead of retrying -- at least this is my experience/understanding of someone else's issues). I've replied to your forum thread with possible alternatives.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion of creating a new project, then trying to download remotely. The SFTP session is timing out before the download is complete, which is the source of my problem here. I will investigate increasing the time constraint.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, to fix it I chose custom for deployment options and then added .sass-cache to the list of things in the "Exclude items by name" field.
I also had to close and re-open phpstorm or it would fail immediately after starting the download.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: It's literally step-by-step how to fix the problem OP is having. Defining what an answer is by the length of the text is stupid. It answers the question. If that doesn't fit the definition the site admins are using, it's the definition that's bad, not the post.